# PackageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo with GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES returning null signing info

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I am trying to get the signatures from an apk file prior to installing, however I am getting null signingInfo object. The PackageInfo is properly populated with all of the other data related to the package.

If I install the apk, then use getPackageInfo, the signingInfo will be populated. Not sure why its failing to obtain it from the apk itself.

Am I missing something on getting a signature from an apk file?

```
    // This call works after installing the apk, it is able to pull the signature without issues
    @Override
    public boolean isPackageSignatureValid(final String packageName)
    {
        try
        {
            android.content.pm.PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, android.content.pm.PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES);

            return validateSignature(packageInfo);
        }
        catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException notFoundException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Calling this on the apk file prior to install, signingInfo is always null
    @Override
    public boolean isApkSignatureValid(final String apkFilePath)
    {
        android.content.pm.PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkFilePath, android.content.pm.PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES);

        return validateSignature(packageInfo);
    }

    private boolean validateSignature(final PackageInfo packageInfo)
    {
        Signature[] signatures;

        if (packageInfo == null || packageInfo.signingInfo == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (packageInfo.signingInfo.hasMultipleSigners())
        {
            signatures = packageInfo.signingInfo.getApkContentsSigners();
        }
        else
        {
            signatures = packageInfo.signingInfo.getSigningCertificateHistory();
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> packageHashes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Signature sig : signatures)
        {
            // I know this is not the best way of doing this, please ignore for now as its not the main issue
            packageHashes.add(sig.hashCode());
        }

        return isHashValid(packageHashes);
    }
```

Comment: What version of Android? An emulator or a real device?

Comment: And have you checked the logcat? The PackageManager may fail to parse the package.

Comment: It is successfully loading in PackgeInfo. It has the proper details of the package itself, however signingInfo is what is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES) flag is added starting from API level 28.

Before that you can use [`GET_SIGNATURES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#GET_SIGNATURES).

If `getPackageArchiveInfo()` still returns null in API 28+, you can back to the deprecated `GET_SIGNATURES` flag.

Starting from API level Tiramisu, `getPackageArchiveInfo()` is deprecated, and [this version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPackageArchiveInfo(java.lang.String,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags)) can be used instead which accepts `PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags` flag set instead of `PackageManager` flags.

Comment: We eventually gave the deprecated call a shot and signatures was populated, so we concluded the version of Android we are on must have a bug in that call. Thank you for the recommendation, this would have saved us if we hadn't found that workaround